# Get the code to build an existing layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

I was just wondering if there was any software to basically take an existing android xml layout and generate the java Activity class that'd create this very specific activity?

Comment: What do you mean? Its literally 1 line of code to display the xml in an Activity.

Comment: I created a fragment that is very repetitive in its content form. So I’d like to generate it with code in the class instead of simply call findViewById for each view. So is there a way to take all the existing views in an activity and generate the code for creating layouts and views that are already written in the xml file. Hope I was clear. :)

Comment: Ah, i see what you mean. You want a plugin that will take an xml and create the whole ViewTree programatically. Not to my knowledge, no. And i have a hard time understanding why you would want this in your code.

Comment: That’s what I meant. My goal is then to simply take the hierarchy of my variables view to generate them in a loop.

Comment: Take a look at the [Butter Knife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife) library. It uses annotations to automatically inject your view variables from inflated XML layouts. It also allows you to inject other things in a similar manner, such as listeners, controllers, etc.

Comment: @corsair992 It seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!